# Pillow, add and rotate text in a image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to add text such as 'H' in an image. And then, rotate the text. I try to use the Pillow 6.0 module in python to do this.
Here is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageOps

img_1 = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100), (255, 255, 255))
img_2 = Image.new("L", (100, 100), 255)

font = ImageFont.load_default()
font_size = 20
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_2)
draw.text((50, 50), "H", fill=0, font=font)
rot_im = img_2.rotate(45, expand=False)
img_1.paste(rot_im)
img_1.save('./generated_img/im_1.png')
```

## I expected this:

[image]

## But I got this:

[image]

## Question:

1. How can I make the black part just as the white background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`rotate`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate) has a `fillcolor` parameter*. You could set that to "white".

```
rot_im = img_2.rotate(45, expand=False, fillcolor="white")
```

(*[in versions of PIL 5.20 and above](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/5.2.0.html?highlight=fillcolor#image-rotate))